# Bluebird promisify vs promisifyAll Performance compare when want to promisification of one method from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, promise, bluebird

I want to know performance difference between bluebird promisify vs promisifyAll.

I have tried performance test of **bluebird** promisify and promisifyAll.

But time and memory wise i do not see major difference, Still i thought promisify is slightly fast and less memory occupy. Still what is best.

Suppose i want Promisification of renderFile of ejs module for just 1 method renderFile.

I have 2 options

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const renderFile = Promise.promisify(ejs.renderFile, {context: ejs});
```

or

```
const ejs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('ejs'));
```

I test performance via

```
console.time('A');
console.timeEnd('A');
```

and `console.log(process.memoryUsage());`

**Pls answer about what should i use when i want promisification of only 1 method.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which method of promisification you are using does not affect the performance of the promisified method at all.

Of course, calling `promisify` will do less work than calling `promisifyAll`, but since both would be called only once during startup of your program, it does not matter in practice.